# Twitter- Obtaining a request token Response 401 - POST

Tags: post, twitter, oauth

I'm trying to create an app with twitter and I'm stuck in the first step.

I'm trying to POST to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token , But everytime I get a 401.

I'm using a varient of Apache Commns HTTPClient's POST method, very specific to my tool, So I'll just post the highlevel picture.

```
My Header:   'oAuth '+
             'oauth_callback="oob",'+
             'oauth_consumer_key="zhaD2Y6RrQaaZQSz21RShA",'+// fake
             'oauth_nonce="'+ <random string of 32Characters>  +'",'+
             'oauth_signature="'+ a.signature +'",'+
             'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",'+
             'oauth_timestamp="'+ <Time in seconds since UNIX epoc> +'"';
```

I'm generating the Signature in this method:

Step1: Percentage Encoding Key-Value pairs, and Appending them as given in the Twitter's Signature page.

Step2: Appending POST and the URL, after percentage encoding. This is what I'm left with:

```
POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%20%3D%20zhaD2Y6RrQaaZQSz21RShA%26oauth_nonce%3DkYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1318622958,
```

So far so good..

My problem starts here, The next step is signing the key, and it needs two things :

1. Consumer Secret of your application
2. The access token ( as this https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature page says)

append these two, with  & and then do a HMAC-SHA1. But how do I get my accesstoken?

I'm yet to send my POST to twitter right? Does access token here mean the Bearer token?

The page doesn't even mention how to get the access token(it actually does, But I'm doing a POST to get this access token right?!)

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that there are several steps to OAuth 1.0a which is used by Twitter:

Step 1: Request an unauthorized request token from Twitter

Step 2: Twitter will respond with a request token and request token secret

Step 3: Send the user to Twitter with the request token to get authorization from the user for your app

Step 4: Twitter will respond with a verification code

Step 5: Send the request token and verifcation code to Twitter to obtain an access token

Step 6: Twitter will respond with an access token and access token secret

Step 7: Use the access token and access token secret to make requests to the Twitter api

At each stage of the process the request must be signed using the consumer key and appropriate token secret. At Step 1 we only have the consumer secret so the signing key is constructed by appending the ampersand character to the percent encoded consumer secret.
It is also worth noting here that your signature base string above is missing the oauth_version parameter and the base string should not end with a comma.

Once you have obtained the request token and request token secret (Step 2), you can send the user to the Twitter authorize url to grant authorization to your app. This is achieved by appending the request token to the authorize url as a querystring and getting the user to visit that url (Step 3). i.e.

https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?request_token=NPxxxxy0yU5T3tBzho7iCotZ3cnetKwcTIRlX0iwRl0
Note this request does not need to be signed.

Once the user has logged in to Twitter and authorized your app, they will receive a verifcation code (oauth_verifier) to pass back to your application (Step 4).

You then make a request to Twitter to exchange the request token for an access token. This is achieved by POSTing a signed request which includes the oauth_verifier code to the Twitter access token url (https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token). The signing key is constructed using the percent encoded consumer secret appended to the percent encoded request token secret using the ampersand character (Step 5).

If all is ok, Twitter will respond with an access_token and access_token_secret (Step 6). You can use these tokens to make all future requests on behalf of the user (Step 7). The signing key for these requests is constructed using the percent encoded consumer secret appended to the percent encoded access token secret using the ampersand character.

On a last note, a bearer token is part of OAuth 2 which has a completely different authorization flow to OAuth 1.0a.

If you need to check your OAuth signatures you can use a utility such as [this one](https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console).

Comment: @Jon Susiak What does this step mean exactly? This is where I'm lost:
> The signing key is constructed using the percent encoded consumer secret appended to the percent encoded request token secret using the ampersand character (Step 5).